Working with API in HTML--how do I send the API data and display it's response in my iframe?
Here is a snippet of code from one of my newer html projects:
<form action='https://www.Bing.com/' method='PUT'>
  <div>
    <label for='newTab'>New Tab?</label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='newTab' id='newTab'/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='newTab'>What do you want to search?</label>
    <input name='/search?q=' id='/search?q=' value='Shopping' />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Search</button>
  </div>
</form>

What it's supposed to do is interact with the Bing API and return the search specified-for example here I want to generate a search for "shopping", I took two values from the Bing API- the 'newTab' value and the '/search?q' value to send the information to, but when I send the information, instead of displaying the search bar with "shopping", it displays the Bing homepage.
As you may be able to tell, I'm new to using APIs at all, especially in HTML-- could anybody help me debug this?

Assuming your form is inside the iframe, this should do the trick.


<form action='https://www.Bing.com/search' method='GET'>
  <div>
    <label for='newTab'>New Tab?</label>
    <input type='checkbox' name='newTab' id='newTab'/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for='search'>What do you want to search?</label>
    <input name='q' id='search' value='Shopping' />
  </div>
  <div>
    <button>Search</button>
  </div>
</form>



Also you can read up on some documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp
